# Keras Mean-Variance Loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am implementing a face estimation model where I am using a pretrained ResNet50 and added some layers on top. Now I would like to implement a Mean-Variance Loss in Keras but I am very new to Keras and just couldn't figure out how.

This is how the last layers of my model look like (where the predict layer contains a sigmoid):

Last Layers:

[image]

Right now I train the model with the following loss:

```
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),metrics=['mae'])
```

I know that I just have to replace the MeanSquaredError by my custom function but I don't know how to implement the Mean-Variance-Loss.

Comment: What do you call a mean-variance-loss exactly?

Comment: I found it in this paper (page 3) where they implement it together with a softmax: https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Pan_Mean-Variance_Loss_for_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf
It consists of two losses, where the mean loss penalizes the difference between the mean of the estimated age distribution and the ground truth of the age and the variance loss does the same for the variance of the estimated age distribution.